# What is wrong about this proof?

Tags: real-analysis, fake-proofs

Statement: if $f(x)\ge0$ for all x, and  $\int_a^\infty f(x)dx$ converges for some constant a>0, then $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=0$.

The statement is in fact wrong, and I know it, but I mananged to give a proof and I don't know what is wrong about it.

My proof:

By contradiction,assume the limit is not 0. Then, there exsists some $\varepsilon_0>0$, and an $x_0$, such that for all $x>x_0$:

$|f(x)-0|=|f(x)|=f(x)\ge \varepsilon_0$.

Define $g(x)=\varepsilon_0$, we know that for all $x>x_0:
g(x)\le f(x)$.

$\int_a^\infty g(x)dx=\lim_{M\to \infty} \varepsilon_0(M-a)=\infty$

Both functions are non-negative, therefore by the comparison test, the spoken integral of f(x) diverges, in contradiction to the fact that it converges.

Comment: You assumed there is a limit at all.

Comment: Of course you assumed it. But the function can be sometimes 0, sometimes 1, changing infinitely many times and then it neither has a limit, nor satisfies your claim about $f\geq \epsilon$.

Comment: We should assume $\lim f(x) > 0$.  But you assumed $\liminf f(x)> 0$.  For a counterexample, consider a case with $\liminf f(x) = 0$ and $\limsup f(x) = 1$.

Comment: The negation of "f does not have a limit of $0$ at $\infty$" is not the one you state. It should be: there exists some $\epsilon_0 > 0$ such that for every $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ there exists $x > x_0$ with $|f(x)| \ge \epsilon_0$. See also the example by Michal in another comment and compare both statements in that case.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): take your favorite counterexample (since you said you know the statement is wrong), and follow your "proof" step by step with that counterexample in hand, to locate and understand the flaw.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take another example from the box of counter-examples, with

$$f(x)=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{cl}
n &\text{ if } x\in \left[n,n+\frac1{n^3}\right) \text{ for positive integer } n  \\ 
0 &\text{ otherwise }  
\end{array}
\right.$$

This satisfies your conditions as you have $\int\limits_0^\infty f(x)\,dx = \sum\limits_1^\infty \frac1{n^2} =\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

but your statement

> there exists some $\varepsilon_0>0$, and an $x_0$, such that for all $x>x_0$: $|f(x)-0|=|f(x)|=f(x)\ge \varepsilon_0$

is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

The statemente is not true because you can pick a function such as follows.

$$
f(x)=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{}
1 \text{, if } x\in\mathbb{Q}  \\ 
0 \text{, if } x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}  
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

The function doesn't have a limit, still the integral converges.

In your proof instead you are assuming the function has a limit.

Comment: Probably a bit of a nitpick, but OP is probably working with the Riemann integral, in which case $f$ is not integrable. I could be wrong though, but the terminology "the integral converges" is quite suggestive of it being a Riemann integral

Comment: $f$ should be Riemann integrable because it is continuous almost everywhere as $\mathbb{Q}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It is not continuous almost everywhere, in fact it is discontinuous everywhere. You probably have mixed it up with the function where you put $1/q$ in the rational case.

Comment: @jc_ since $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ are both dense in $\mathbb{R}$, we can, for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, find sequences $\{a_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $\{b_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ which both converge to $x$ and which are such that $f(a_j)\to0$ and $f(b_j)\to1$ as $j\to\infty$, so $f$ is discontinuous everywhere, and consequently not Riemann integrable on any interval by the exact theorem you cite

Comment: In fact, this exact function is probably the most common example of a function which is Lebesgue integrable but not Riemann integrable (on intervals)

Answer (score 0):

An example can be provided by a concise formula:
$$f(x)=(1-|\sin x|)^{x^2/\pi^2},\quad x\ge \pi$$
Then the limit points of $f(x)$ at infinity coincide with the interval $[0,1]$ and the function is integrable. Indeed
$$\int\limits_\pi^\infty f(x)\,dx =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int\limits_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} f(x)\,dx= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int\limits_{0}^{\pi} f(x+n\pi)\,dx$$
Next
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\pi} f(x+n\pi)\,dx\le \int\limits_0^\pi (1-\sin x)^{n^2}\,dx=2\int\limits_0^{\pi/2} (1-\sin x)^{n^2}\,dx\\ \le
2\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\left (1-{2\over \pi}x\right )^{n^2}\,dx ={4\over \pi (n^2+1)}$$